# Letting user to create a form and add the object in database

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, formbuilder

I'm starting to work on **Fleet Management app** which will have feature:
Letting user create a vehicle and a form for its inspection.

I want my web-app to allow user to create a vehicle and inspection questions (odometer , fuel, and other readings). This will lead to an table creation in the database which will store all the inspections.

I'm having hard time to figure out how to get it done in **Spring Boot**.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: That is a very broad question, perhaps you can narrow it down to what you are specifically struggling with, detailing what you have tried?  As I dont know what your level of understanding with respect to Spring Boot, I suggest you try working through some of their guides (https://spring.io/guides), this seems to cover one of your requirements https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have a spring-boot app configured already? if yes, you'll need to create RestContrller for a start, this is very broad question, do your research first...